# Create Array from Mysql data for Flot

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, flot

I have a problem in that I can't get an array into an array.

The outcome should look like this:

```
$data=array(
  array(
     'label' => 'Totals',
     'color' => '#745fa4',
     'data' => 
    array(
      array('01/01/2015', 125),
      array('02/01/2015', 148),
      array('03/01/2015', 42),
      array('04/01/2015', 115),
      array('05/01/2015', 45),
      array('06/01/2015', 77),
      array('07/01/2015', 59)
    )
  ),
);
```

**I currently have this but can't get it into the correct format:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 28");

$chartdata = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $chartdata[] .= array($row["date"]. ", " . $row["total"]);
    }

$data=array(
  array(
     'label' => 'Totals',
     'color' => '#745fa4',
     'data' => $chartdata
  )
);
```

If someone could help me out that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `.=` this means assignment with string concatenation. you should push array into parent array

2) inside child array have two values not single string so use `,` between two value not string concatenation `","`

```
$chartdata[] .= array($row["date"]. ", " . $row["total"]);
```

to

```
$chartdata[] = array($row["date"],  $row["total"]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the others removing the . after $chartdata[] which didn't work but the answer you gave has worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have a superfluous dot here:

```
#            ⇓  
$chartdata[] .= array($row["date"]. ", " . $row["total"]);
```

To push new item into an array one should use `$array[] = $item`:

```
$chartdata[] = array($row["date"]. ", " . $row["total"]);
```

Dot is used to concatenate strings. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot.

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 28");

$chartdata = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $chartdata[] = array($row["date"],  $row["total"]); // Remove the dot
    }

$data=array(
  array(
     'label' => 'Totals',
     'color' => '#745fa4',
     'data' => $chartdata
  )
);
```